# Для чего необходимо вводить аннотацию @Entity при определение класса , Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, framework

Не совсем ясно в чем смысл этой аннотации когда есть @Table которая явно указывает с какой таблицей идет связь.

Comment: Как иначе Hibernate определит, что данный класс соответствует каким-то таблицам? Проверяя у каждого класса наличие аннотаций на полях?

Comment: @etki с помощью аннотации "@Table мы говорим Hibernate с какой именно таблицей необходимо связать данный класс.

Comment: Это опциональная аннотация, которой может и не быть

Answer (score 4):

Аннотацией `@Entity` отмечаются классы, которые представляют собой сущности базы данных. Например, если в базе данных есть таблица User, которая содержит список пользователей, в Java должен существовать класс User, отмеченный аннотацией `@Entity`, объектом этого класса будет строка таблицы User. Часто используется совместно с аннотацией `@Table`, которая помогает явно определить некоторую информацию о таблице.